# MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload [obejct Object

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, private-blockchain, metamask

I am trying to sign transactions using certify_send() function to a smart contract deployed to my private ethereum blockchain but I keep getting this error after I approve in MetaMask

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {
  "id": 6657017249622,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "params": ["<a long hex string>"],
  "method": "eth_sendRawTransaction"
} [object Object]
```

This is my app.js

```
var contract = undefined;
var customProvider = undefined;
var address = "0xfBB02839E0DFCaFd6ca4784399E28F3091b8F072";
var abi = undefined;

function certify_init () {
  //set up network
  // if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use existing gateway
    // window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  if (window.ethereum) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
    window.ethereum.enable();
  } else {
    alert("No Ethereum interface injected into browser. Read-only access");
  }
  //contract abi
  let abi = [
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "bytes32",
          "name": "hash",
          "type": "bytes32"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "insti",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "reci",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "course",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "grade",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "doc",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "addDocHash",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "bytes32",
          "name": "hash",
          "type": "bytes32"
        }
      ],
      "name": "findDocHash",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "constructor"
    }
  ];

  //init contract
  contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
  // contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address, {
  //   from: acc, // default from address
  //   gasPrice: '20000000000' // default gas price in wei, 20 gwei in this case
  // });
  console.log(contract.methods);
};

//sends a hash to the blockchain
function certify_send (hash, insti, reci, course, grade, doc, callback) {
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function (error, accounts) {
      console.log("Account="+accounts[0]);
      contract.methods.addDocHash(hash, insti, reci, course, grade, doc).send({
        from: accounts[0],
        gas: 20000000,
        gasLimit: 8000000
      },function(error, tx) {
        if (error) callback(error, null);
        else callback(null, tx);
      });
    });
};

//looks up a hash on the blockchain
function certify_find (hash, callback) {
  contract.methods.findDocHash(hash).call( function (error, result) {
    if (error) callback(error, null);
    else {
      let resultObj = {
        mineTime:  new Date(result[0] * 1000),
        blockNumber: result[1],
        instituteName: result[2],
        recipientName: result[3],
        courseName: result[4],
        marks: result[5],
        dateOfCompletion: result[6]
      }
      callback(null, resultObj);
    }
  });
};
```

How to resolve this issue??

Comment: Sometimes that error appears when the nonce cached by Metamask doesn't match the real one, in that case you can try reseting your account in Metamask's settings. If that doesn't work you will to create an issue in Metamask's repo.